# S3 static website bucket not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was previously hosting my static website on S3, but I lost access to that account when my Android phone with the 2FA on it died, and customer support has not accepted my proof of ID/address.

I have another AWS account, but when I tried to have it host my domain as a static website, the bucket was not available (as my other account had created it on S3).
The [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)
doesn't mention any way of hosting a static domain if the bucket name does not match the domain.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can't fix that. You need to contact AWS support and work with them to get your old account back, or at least work with them to get the S3 bucket name back.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 bucket names are **globally unique** across all worldwide regions. If a bucket exists with a given name, that name cannot be used again until the bucket is deleted.

When hosting a static website on Amazon S3 with **your own domain name**, the bucket name must be the same as the domain, eg `www.example.com`.

It appears that your bucket name is still "in use" by your old account. You'll either need to:

- **Regain access** to that account (perhaps by proving knowledge of the credit card and verifying an email address), or
- Requesting that the bucket be **deleted** because you own the matching domain name

You should try [contacting AWS Customer Service](https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/) (billing & account enquiries).

Comment: Workaround: pick a new bucket name, which won't matter, in the following setup... configure a CloudFront distribution pointing to the new bucket's web site hosting endpoint as the origin and with the desired domain name as an alternate name on the distribution, then point the DNS to CloudFront.  In this configuration there is no need for the bucket name to match the domain name.  But really... the answer here is the correct one. +1

Comment: Ooh, nice alternative! Also benefits from caching content so users have a faster experience.